# JSON GET -> output as text

Tags: javascript, json, get

I have another question again.

Please keep in mind that I am learning CSS, HTML and JS for around 2 weeks now...I am still a noob.

I have a .js stored outside, which I need to GET and then store it as simple string in a -Element.

My problem is that I do not yet understand how to use GET and how to transform the json into a usable string (text).

Could someone give me an example on that?

Comment: Using JQuery?
Can you post your current code?

Comment: Do you use ajax ? If so, you can specify that you want "Text" instead of "JSon"

Comment: `obj = $.get("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/?");  
  obj2 = JSON.parse(joke);
  document.getElementById("line").innerHTML=
  obj2.value.joke;
`           Thats the test code, which I put into a "button.click-event. The problem is, its not working and I dont know why. Oh and I am using jquery ;)

Comment: Great...I cant edit my last comment. Second line looks like this: `obj2 = JSON.parse(obj);`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option in plain JavaScript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onload = function () {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var text = request.responseText;
        // text is now a string. use text ..
    } else {
        // failure
    }
};
request.send();
```

This is a reference to [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to GET the data and then use `JSON.stringify(value)` if `value` was your JSON object.

```
$.get("my.json", function(value) {
  $("body")
    .append(JSON.stringify(value));
}, "json");
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the reference for `stringyfy()`. [Here's](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) the reference for jQuery's GET.